# Bulk action in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I am using bulk action in my model.I have switched to django1.2 beta. I want to know that when I perform a bulk action on selected data ,it is not shown on 'action list'(recent actions) displayed at the starting page of django.But if I do some changes manually means as perform in earlier versions then it shows in action list.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose you mean 1.1beta – there's no 1.2 yet.

To address the question, I've just tried with the latest version of Django trunk (what's to become Django 1.1), and there bulk delete is logged just fine. I suppose it might have been fixed since the beta version you're using was released.